# How to adjust the margins in Plotly Dash DAQ components?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I've created a gauge plot using the Plotly dash DAQ [gauge component](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-daq/gauge) and need to reduce the bottom margin as it's excessive. Any ideas?

I've tried using multiple configs for margins in the style components (see code example) but this hasn't worked.

```py
import dash_daq as daq

daq.Gauge(
    style={
        'color': Colors.text,
        'marginBottom': '0px',
        'margin-bottom': '0px'
    },
    min=0,
    max=100,
    value=25,
    size=200,
    showCurrentValue=True,
    units='%',
    labelPosition='bottom',
    label={
        'label': 'Female',
        'style': {
            'color': Colors.text,
            'fontSize': 14
        }
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post a picture of your actual plot ?

Comment: Added the image as a [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvUPq.png) - Still new so can't embed the image

Comment: Just copy the image and paste it in your post, as easy as that !

Comment: So you want something like [this](https://imgur.com/a/eV35qoq) ?

Comment: Yes exactly that! Also, can't post images yet as my rep points are too low

Comment: Did you try negative margins? It's possible to do. What do you get with `'margin-bottom': -50` ?

Comment: That worked, thank you! I was nowhere near considering that

Comment: I'm glad it worked ! Added it as an answer so it doesn't get left as an unanswered question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try negative margins:

```
import dash_daq as daq

daq.Gauge(
    style={
        'color': Colors.text,

        'margin-bottom': -50 #Or whatever number suits your needs
    },
    min=0,
    max=100,
    value=25,
    size=200,
    showCurrentValue=True,
    units='%',
    labelPosition='bottom',
    label={
        'label': 'Female',
        'style': {
            'color': Colors.text,
            'fontSize': 14
        }
    }
)
```